# Table with div layers

Tags: css, layer, css-tables

I have a table inside a div 1.

Then after that div 1 added another div 2 with `position:relative; top:-250;` so that div 2 layer will be right on top of the table. 
But now below the table there is a big space before anything on the page can resume displaying (I guess the second div 2 would have normally been without the -250 position change?)
How do I get rid of the space and clear it?
I tried this... `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` ...and it didn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute positioning rather than relative may do the trick. I'll test this theory and edit my answer accordingly.

Edit: using `position: absolute; margin-top: -250px;` seems to be the solution.